# vlookup formula with variable range in it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add variables into a vlookup formulated function

The one shown below is able to run

```
Cells(17, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17").Address(False, False) & ",'Temp'!B:C,2,False)"
```

But what I am trying to do is to add varibles to replace B:C found in the formula which will look like this

```
Cells(17, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=vlookup(" & Sheets("VPC4").Range("C17").Address(False, False) & ",'Temp'!Cells(Row1,2):Cells(Row2,3),2,False)"
```

where

```
Row1 = Sheets("Temp").Cells.Find(What:="test", SearchDirection:=xlUp, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Row2 = Sheets("Temp").Cells.Find(What:="test1", SearchDirection:=xlUp, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
```

[image]

It isn't performing what i am expected and it showed $name instead. I need the vba to be a formulated output therefore, .formula was used. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `Row1` and `Row2` variable values in this way:

```
Cells(17, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=vlookup(" & Sheets("VPC4").Range("C17").Address(False, False) & ",'Temp'!" & _
                                  range(Cells(Row1,2),Cells(Row2,3)).address & _
                                                         ",2,False)"
```